# Get notifications with text, badge, no sound

Tags: notifications, 8.0-oreo, samsung-galaxy-s-9

I am trying to make wordfeud (and other apps) only show a text popup, update its badge and not make any sound. However, it still plays the notification sound.

I have setup no sound in the app settings of the app.

I have enabled a feature that could possibly change things, I dont know. Its called notification reminders and can be found under the Accessibility settings category. The effect will be that the notification sound it repeated every minute until I pay attention to a notification.

Will those make things different?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I can disable notification reminders per app.
There is yet another set of toggles, one toggle per app.

When I enable notification reminder for an app, I can only choose sound or vibration, which is fine because if I want neither, I just disable reminders for that app.